# How to check if products is empty Laravel with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I want to check if products is empty or not with javascript, when user tries to like or unlike something it should check without refreshing the page. I use eloquent , I have tried something here but it is not strong enough to work, in normal way I check like this

```
@if (Auth::user()->likedProducts->count() > 0 )
@else
@endif
```

Any one with idea on how I can fix this?

User.php

```
 public function likedProducts()
 {
   return $this->morphedByMany('App\Product', 'likeable');
 }
```

Blade File

```
<a style="display: {{Auth::user()->likedProducts->count() > 0 ? "" : "none"}}" id="item" href="{{route('likes')}}"> displays products  </a>

<a style=" display: {{Auth::user()->likedProducts->count() <= 0 ? "" : "none"}}" id="item" href="{{route('likes')}}">You have no products </a>
```

I don't know what to put in javascript, since I have no idea and I have tried to search but didn't get an answer, your help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to create a route that return Auth::user()->likedProducts->count(), then in ajax get the value of it

Comment: You should look into ```XHR``` and ```AJAX```. These technologies allow you to ask the backend for data without refreshing the whole page.

Comment: Creating a route that returns `Auth::user()->likedProducts->count()' passing through controller or view ?because I use model @Melvita

Comment: Yeah I have searched but didn't get what I needed@Kyrre

Comment: You need to do an ajax call and declare a route that return the product count in your laravel project and parse it.

Comment: is very confusing for a beginner @N69S

Comment: @joh attack it little by little, here is a good starting point.https://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/laravel_ajax.htm